# C#/Asp.net Post Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Okay, so here is my code:

```
    var functionAddWord = function () {

    var dictionaryItem = { };
    dictionaryItem.Word = $('#newWordId').val().trim();
    dictionaryItem.Definition = $('#newDefinition').val().trim();
    $.post("/word/", dictionaryItem, function (result) {
        window.alert(result.Word);
    });
};
```

Web API:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "Add or Edit Word",
              routeTemplate: "word",
              defaults: new { Controller = "Values", action = "Post"}
          );
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult<dictionaryItem> Post([FromBody] dictionaryItem Word )
        {
            var dictionaryRepository = new dictionaryRepository();

           dictionaryRepository.addOrEditWord(Word);

            var response = new dictionaryItem { Word = Word.Word, Definition = Word.Definition};
            return Json(response);
        }
```

I have a button that calls to the functionAddWork, which DOES work. The dictionaryItem is set properly, I have tested that as well. The $.post does not call to the controller method properly, and it can't find the controller. Been working on this for 2+ hours and can't figure out what I am missing.

Thank you in advance,
Jay

Comment: What's the controller named? You're calling the relative uri "/word/" but your method is called Post. You don't have any routing in your javascript to that method.

Comment: please provide  1) controller name 2) default route mapping 3) exact error message

Comment: @Necoras the routing is handled by his Web API routes.  `defaults: new { Controller = "Values", action = "Post"}`

Comment: Default "Values" controller.   Default Route: `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );`

Comment: @Amy Ah, duh. Missed that section completely. The javascript is looking for "api/values/word" which isn't a valid route.

Comment: Well i have another method that uses /getword/ that uses a GET function that works 100% `$.get("/word/" + $('#wordValue').val(), {}, function (result) {`

Comment: I think @Necoras found the problem.  Your route is "word".  Not "values/word".  Your request does not match the route.